# Using "snap pour point" to find a watershed of specific area starting from a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, spatial-analyst, watershed

I am trying to find everything downhill of a certain point in order to create a watershed of a specific area.

For example, say I have a point at (x,y), and I'm interested in creating a watershed that is 50 km^2 starting from this point.

One method that I have used of achieving this is placing random pour points downstream and using the watershed analysis tool to create watersheds from (x,y) to the new pour points until I find a point that gives me a watershed of 50 km^2.

Since I need to do this process ~250 times, I'm greatly interested in finding a more efficient method. One idea is using the "snap pour point" tool from the original (x,y) point to find another point that has the highest accumulation within 50 km^2. Unfortunately, the snap distance given in ArcGis is (I assumed) a radius.

Does anyone have any tips that might help me achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.